# bulgarian cyrilic in data in r

Tags: r, encoding

I can't import data with cyrilic. It is Windows-1251, but when set this in the encoding it doesn't work.
It doesn't work with statemnet also:

```
stringmeteo <- read.csv("stringmeteo.csv",encoding="bg-BG")  # read csv file
```

You can find the 5 rows from csv below.

> ```
> > date,air,min,max,irritation,wind_avg,wind_max,wind_porivi,precipitation,pressure,visibility,occurrence1,snow,date_N,year,month,NM,occ1,occ2,occ3,snow_new,occ_snow,rain_occ,occ_snow_rain,f/,f//,w1,w2,w3,x
> > text56789012,-99.9,-99.9,-99.9,-99.9,-99.9,99,99,999.9,9999.9,99.9,text56789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901,txt,,,,text5678901234567890,text5678901234567890,text5678901234567890,text5678901234567890,999,9,9,9,,,text5678901234567890,text5678901234567890,text5678901234567890,
> >   09.01.1976г.  ,-0.2,-5,4,-9,3.5,5,,0,1030.8,45.1,---,---,09/01/1976,1976,1,Dragoman,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,9
> >   18.01.1976г.  ,-6.6,-9,-5,-7.2,7.8,10,,0.3,1018.5,15.9,Сняг/Суграшица,---,18/01/1976,1976,1,Dragoman,Сняг/Суграшица,,,,1,,1,0,0,Сняг/Суграшица,0,0,4
> >   19.01.1976г.  ,-9.3,-10,-8,-11,3,7,,,1026.1,20,---,---,19/01/1976,1976,1,Dragoman,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,2
> >   24.01.1976г.  ,1.6,-3,7,-2.8,2.6,7,,0,1008.8,18,---,---,24/01/1976,1976,1,Dragoman,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,10
> >   26.01.1976г.  ,1.8,0,5,1,1.5,3,,1.5,1009.2,9.5,Сняг/Суграшица,3,26/01/1976,1976,1,Dragoman,Сняг/Суграшица,,,3,1,,1,0,0,Сняг/Суграшица,0,0,5
> ```

When I read this csv the result is not correct. Look at red boxes in the pictures.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODnGa.jpg)

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Looks like you are on Windows. Try `read.csv("stringmeteo.csv", encoding = "UTF-8")`.

Comment: I have copied and pasted the data to a text file and read it in with `read.csv("data.csv")`. No encoding argument. On R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)/Ubuntu 19.10 there was no problem.

Comment: Under windos, but our encoding is not UTF-8.

Comment: I read data but they are not correct. Look at the red boxes in the picture.

Comment: @pverspeelt it is read but incorrect. You can see the image attached above. the same file in Pythot imported by `import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv('stringmeteo_1973_2013.csv',header=1,encoding ='cp1251')`

Comment: It's following [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `stri_encode('Сняг/Суграшица',from="cp1252",to="cp1252")` returns `"Ñíÿã/Ñóãðàøèöà"`. The same (maybe clearer and more instructive) example in Python: `'Сняг/Суграшица'.encode('cp1251').decode('cp1252')` returns `'Ñíÿã/Ñóãðàøèöà'`